What can we do about inappropriate edits from anonymous users?
A question I asked a few years ago, just got a proposed edit from an anonymous user. The edit leaves the question unchanged, but adds this text at the end:

So my question is if this is racist.

I will, of course, reject it. The edit is abusive. As the user who made the inappropriate edit is anonymous, I don't see how to flag them. Is there a way to flag the user?
My question before it was edited, in its entirety:

I created a button using the built-in Button class, and set the button mask to BUTTON_MASK_LEFT | BUTTON_MASK_RIGHT. Now both left- and right-click cause the 'pressed' signal to be emitted, but I need a way to tell whether the user clicked with the left or right mouse button.


How would you flag an anonymous user?

Flag the post as 'In need of moderator intervention' and explain what is going on.

As long as you reject and pick spam/abusive  as reject reason their IP goes into spamram, hopefully slowing them down/blocking them for a certain period..

The "best" the moderator team could do is block list the IP from making suggested edits, but I don't even know if the moderators have that sort of power against IPs. Is this a one off? Your title suggests that this has happened multiple times.

@ThomA It's the first time it's happened to me, but S/O is big enough that it's unlikely to be a unique occurrence.

The two original dupe targets are still relevant, but I added a third which is a slam-dunk target for this issue.

"The user who made the inappropriate edit is anonymous, so I don't see how to flag them" you can't even "flag" an existing user. You can only flag posts. If you need to flag something that's not contained to a post (e.g., pattern of pots, a user, something else) typically you should flag any post and explain why with a custom reason. A post related to the custom reason is probably best but if such a thing does not exist, then you can even flag and of your own posts.

@ThomA IP blocking may not be a solution because many people around the world still use dynamic IPs.

I didn't say it would be a solution, just that's the likely the best that could be done, @AugustoVasques .
